# Is there a function in WINAPI to draw a single character on specified position?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I am looping through a string let's say `str = "Random\a\n\t3content"` and I want to draw the string on the screen by drawing each character, but using functions like `TextOut` or `DrawText` all take in strings and are inefficient or don't work as I intend.

The problem with saying `DrawText(..., str, ..., DT_SINGLELINE)` is that characters like `\a` or `\n` have a width of 0, but I want every character to have the exact same width e.g. a constant value like 13.

I had one idea, but it still seems inefficient:

Use `DrawText` anyways, but create a new string that replaces new line characters and such with spaces.

Is there an efficient way to draw single characters on the screen? Maybe a function that just takes in an `HDC`, a `char` and `x, y` position?

Comment: You can use `DrawText` for sure - there is an `LPRECT lprc` argument that defines the rectangle in which to draw the text (even a single character string); just increment the `x` position of that by the required amount, for each subsequent character.

Comment: _"Use DrawText anyways, but create a new string that replaces new line characters and such with spaces"_: what's wrong with that? Creating a new string takes very little time compared to the call to `DrawText`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I am trying to find an efficient solution and calling `DrawText` 100 times seems inefficient because I don't think the `DrawText` implementation was created for that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I mean, I will do that if there is no reply with another solution.

Comment: `DrawText` accepts the number of characters to draw. You don't have to build a new string just to draw part of it.

Comment: This may be a better problem for [DirectWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/how-to-add-inline-objects-to-a-text-layout)

Comment: @Lost the idea in my first comment is simple and fast.

Comment: @IInspectable Absolutely! Same goes for `TextOut`, which would seem to be more efficient (in a loop) than `DrawText`, as there is no need to constantly pass/use the text alignment parameter.

Comment: Most obvious way to do this is by using a fixed-pitch font.  Which is very efficient and actually looks good, unlike a variable-pitch font drawn at fixed letter positions.

Comment: @HansPassant I am using the Consolas font, a monospace font, still if `TextOut` *sees* a new line, it is ignored and not treated as space (which is not a weird behaviour at all, I just want it to be treated as space).

Answer (score 2):

Although, as you correctly say, the `TextOutA` and `TextOutW`functions take *strings* as their `lpString` argument, you can also use them to print out single characters. Note this paragraph from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textouta):

> `lpString`
>
> A pointer to the string to be drawn. The string does not need to be
> zero-terminated, because *cchString* specifies the length of the string.

Thus, using a value of `1` for the `cchString` argument, we can loop through a given string, plotting each character at a given position (so there is no need for any copying of characters). We only need to set the text-rendering attributes (alignment, colour, *etc.*) *once*, as these are set for the device context.

Given an appropriate device context and bounding rectangle (I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader), the following code snippet shows how to plot characters of (possibly) varying widths at fixed intervals:

```c
void PlotString(HDC hDC, RECT rec, const char* text, int px, int py, int width)
{
    SelectObject(hDC, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    Rectangle(hDC, rec.left, rec.top, rec.right, rec.bottom);
    SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SetTextAlign(hDC, TA_TOP | TA_CENTER | TA_NOUPDATECP);
    for (const char* c = text; *c; ++c) {
        TextOutA(hDC, px, py, c, 1);
        px += width;
    }
}
```

This seems pretty 'efficient' to me!

Comment: This might be a good input for someone. I should have added this: This is what I have started with. This is what I about had when I asked the question. I called this inefficient because of the many `TextOut` calls instead of just once (which does not work (problem stated in my question)) or using some native put char function or something.

Comment: @Lost I don't really see how multiple calls of `TextOut` is any less efficient than multiple (similar) calls to any hypothetical `PutChar` function. The only difference would be one less argument to the call (the last).

Comment: @Lost if you're doing multiple `DrawText` calls in short succession you may be better off looking at [`DirectWrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/text-formatting-and-layout) which allows you to do quite a bit more low level text tinkering down geometry and layout. But without understanding your use case it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @AdrianMole `TextOut`, like many other GDI functions, taps into the GDI display driver, which may involve the kernel. Crossing the kernel barrier -- like invoking a driver function -- has associated cost to it, so you'd want to do as few of driver invocations as possible, "batching work". Microsoft hints to as much with the sentence "Additionally, ExtTextOut will perform internal batching of calls before transitioning to kernel mode..." at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polytextouta. DirectWrite has a different pipeline which batches "automatically".